# Subscript out of range error in Excel VBA when I add a new worksheet at the end of the list of worksheets only when the VB window is closed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, office365

I have built an Excel Workbook that is intended for evaluation of an organization as a whole and then evaluation of each of several sites for that organization. There is an initial assessment and then an on-site assessment for the organization, and for each facility. Depending on the organization, the number of facilities will vary. There is a first "Configuration" tab where the user of the workbook enters (or copies and pastes) the list of facilities and determines which facilities are to be included in the evaluation.

The second and third worksheets are the assessment for the organization as a whole, and the fourth and fifth worksheets are template assessment forms for the facilities.

Once the list of facilities is entered, the user clicks on a button labeled "Create Facility Tabs" that steps through the facility list and creates the needed worksheets for each facility.

If the list is fresh (starting from its initial form), then the template worksheets are renamed for the first facility and new worksheets are created for the remainder.

If there are already worksheets identified, the software checks each facility to see if its page already exists, and only creates additional worksheets for newly added facilities.

When additional worksheets are needed, the code first counts the number of additional worksheets that are needed (two for each facility), creates those worksheets, and then steps through them copying the template contents onto the forms and the change code for the worksheets into the worksheet's module.

The software works perfectly over and over again *when I have the VBA window open*. It does everything it is supposed to do. **However**, when I close the VBA window, the code creates all the worksheets, copies everything into the first worksheet, and then raises a Subscript Out of Range error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub CreateFacilities()
   
    Dim row As Long
    Dim facility_name As String
    Dim facility_list As String
    Dim facilities As Variant
    Dim include As Boolean
    Dim ws_init As Worksheet
    Dim ws_fac As Worksheet
    Dim ws_new_init As Worksheet
    Dim ws_new_fac As Worksheet
    Dim ws_config As Worksheet
    Dim facility_count As Long
    Dim tabs_to_create As Long
    Dim fac_initial_range As Range
    Dim fac_initial_address As String
    Dim fac_onsite_range As Range
    Dim fac_onsite_address As String
    Dim message As String
    Dim title As String
    Dim answer As Variant
    Dim code_line As String
    Dim b_width As Long
    Dim c_width As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim init_sheet_number As Long
    Dim fac_sheet_number As Long
    Dim tab_count As Long
            
    title = "Creating Facility Tabs"
    message = "Before you execute this function you should" & vbCrLf & "add any study-specific questions to the" & vbCrLf
    message = message & "Initial Assessment - Facility1 and" & vbCrLf & "On-Site Assessment - Facility1 tabs so" & vbCrLf
    message = message & "they will be included on the created facility tabs" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    message = message & "Do you wish to continue?"
    
    answer = MsgBox(message, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, title)
    
    If answer = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
    Set ws_config = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration")
    Set ws_init = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
    Set ws_fac = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5)
    b_width = ws_init.Columns("B").ColumnWidth
    c_width = ws_init.Columns("C").ColumnWidth
    
    Set fac_initial_range = ws_init.Range("A1:C" & Trim(Str(FindLastRow(ws_init))))
    Set fac_onsite_range = ws_fac.Range("A1:C" & Trim(Str(FindLastRow(ws_fac))))
    fac_initial_address = fac_initial_range.address
    fac_onsite_address = fac_onsite_range.address
    
    code_line = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.Lines(1, 50)  'get code for each new worksheet
    
    facility_list = ""              'get list of facilities
    facility_count = 0
    For row = 4 To 54
        facility_name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration").cells(row, 2).value
        include = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration").cells(row, 4).value

        If facility_name = "" Then                                  'reached the end of the list
            Exit For
        Else:
            If include Then                                         'the Do Assessment column is marked TRUE
                If Not WorksheetExists(facility_name) Then          'the tabs for this facility do not already exist
                    facility_list = facility_list & facility_name & ","
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next row
    
    facility_list = Left(facility_list, Len(facility_list) - 1)     'remove trailing comma
    
    If facility_list = "" Then                                      'no new facilities were added to the list
        MsgBox "There were no facilties specified for inclusion"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    facilities = Split(facility_list, ",")                          'there is a list of facilities to add
    facility_count = UBound(facilities) + 1
    
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count = 5 Then                         'no facility tabs have been added
        If facility_count = 1 Then                                  'there is only one facility - no tabs need to be added
            tabs_to_create = 0
            facility_name = facilities(0)
            ws_init.Name = CreateInitialTabName(facility_name)
            ws_fac.Name = CreateOnSiteTabName(facility_name)
        Else:
            tabs_to_create = (facility_count - 1) * 2
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count), Count:=tabs_to_create
            For counter = LBound(facilities) To UBound(facilities)
                facility_name = facilities(counter)
                If counter = 0 Then                             'rename the first two facility worksheets that already exist
                    ws_init.Name = CreateInitialTabName(facility_name)
                    ws_fac.Name = CreateOnSiteTabName(facility_name)
                Else:                                           'for the rest, add worksheets and copy template content and code
                    init_sheet_number = ((counter - 1) * 2) + 6
                    fac_sheet_number = init_sheet_number + 1
                    
                    Set ws_new_init = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(init_sheet_number)  'create initial assessment sheet for facility
                    ws_new_init.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = b_width
                    ws_new_init.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = c_width
                    ws_new_init.Name = CreateInitialTabName(facility_name)
                    fac_initial_range.Copy Destination:=ws_new_init.Range("A1")
                    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws_new_init.CodeName).CodeModule.AddFromString code_line
                    
                    Set ws_new_fac = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fac_sheet_number)    'create on-site assessment sheet for facility
                    ws_new_fac.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = b_width
                    ws_new_fac.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = c_width
                    ws_new_fac.Name = CreateOnSiteTabName(facility_name)
                    fac_onsite_range.Copy Destination:=ws_new_fac.Range("A1")
                    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws_new_fac.CodeName).CodeModule.AddFromString code_line
                End If
            Next counter
        End If
    Else:                                                       'there are more than 5 tabs in the workbook - some were already added
        tab_count = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        tabs_to_create = facility_count * 2
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tab_count), Count:=tabs_to_create
        For counter = LBound(facilities) To UBound(facilities)
            facility_name = facilities(counter)
            init_sheet_number = (counter * 2) + (tab_count + 1)
            fac_sheet_number = init_sheet_number + 1
            Set ws_new_init = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(init_sheet_number)
            Set ws_new_fac = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(fac_sheet_number)
            ws_new_init.Name = CreateInitialTabName(facility_name)
            ws_new_fac.Name = CreateOnSiteTabName(facility_name)
            ws_new_init.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = b_width
            ws_new_fac.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = b_width
            ws_new_init.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = c_width
            ws_new_fac.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = c_width
            fac_initial_range.Copy Destination:=ws_new_init.Range("A1")
            fac_onsite_range.Copy Destination:=ws_new_fac.Range("A1")
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws_new_init.CodeName).CodeModule.AddFromString code_line
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws_new_fac.CodeName).CodeModule.AddFromString code_line
        Next counter
    End If
    ws_config.Activate
    MsgBox Str(facility_count) & " facilities added"
 End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: this has taken me a lot of work to find out since I could not replicate the problem while the debugger is running. It turns out that the problems occurs on the line that attempts to write code to the Worksheet module for each newly created worksheet. When I comment those lines of code out, everything works fine. The line is "ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ws_new_init.CodeName).CodeModule.AddFromString code_line"

Comment: I am not sure, if this is the answer: did you check "Trust access to VBA project object model" in the macro security settings (On the Excel ribbon: DEVELOPER->Macro Security and tick "Trust access to VBA project object model".)

Comment: More information, I put some message boxes in place to look at the value of ws_new_init.CodeName and it appears that this value is populated when the VBA editor is running but not when the VBA editor is shut down. When VBA is running, the messagebox reads "The code name for Facility2-Initial is Sheet43". When the VBA window is closed it reads "The code name for Facility2-Initial is ".

Comment: Ike, Thank you for bringing this up. I had no idea it was there. However, it appears to me that that setting is checked (has a check mark in the box). The setting is also unable to be edited, so I cannot try to unset it and set it again.

Comment: You never set the `codename` of worksheets - only the `name` - at least I can't find an according code line

Comment: Ike, I was referring to the "Trust access to VBA project object model" setting. I can see it, and the checkbox is checked, but the setting is disabled (I cannot change the trust setting) which makes me think that maybe my company has made this decision for me.

Comment: If it is checked,  then it's ok - wondering that your company activates it by default as this is a known security issue ... did you read my last comment regarding not setting codename

Comment: What is the code that you are adding to the new sheet ? Could you not use a hidden sheet with the code on as a template to create the new sheets. ?